# how to unset array which has empty value using php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to unset two array value which has zero value...

```
$array1=Array ( [0] => SL [1] => S [2] => M [3] => L [4] => F ) 
$array2=Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => 22 [2] => 35 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 )
```

always first array and second array keys are same. i wanna check second array value is empty or not if empty then i need to remove values from both the array

I need output:

```
Array ( [0] => SL [1] => S [2] => M  ) 
Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => 22 [2] => 35 )
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: Looking at the expected output, you've removed items that's non-empty as well? (like [3] => L and [4] => F). The question and the expected output doesn't match.

Comment: foreach($array1 as $key){
    foreach($array2 as $array_item){
            if($array_item==0){
               unset($array1[$key]);
      unset($array2[$key]);
        }
    }
 }

Comment: yeah i wanna remove two array index and value when second array value is 0

Comment: Please update the _question_ with the proper (all) information and any code. Don't post code and additional info in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array_filter,

```
$array2 = array_filter($array2);
$array1 = array_filter($array1, function($k)use($array2){return isset($array2[$k]);}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the index of array1 corresponds to the index of array2, you just need to find the indexes of $array2 whose values are 0. Once you've done that, just unset the elements with the given index from both arrays.

```
foreach($array2 as $key=>$value){
    if($value === 0){
        unset($array2[$key]);
        unset($array1[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeZeroValues($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value === 0) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $array;
}

$array1 = array("SL", "S", "M", "L", "F");
$array2 = array(15, 22, 35, 0, 0);

$array1 = removeZeroValues($array1);
$array2 = removeZeroValues($array2);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array1);
print_r($array2);
```

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => SL
    [1] => S
    [2] => M
    [3] => L
    [4] => F
)
Array
(
    [0] => 15
    [1] => 22
    [2] => 35
)  but i need Array ( [0] => SL [1] => S [2] => M  ) 
Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => 22 [2] => 35 )